# MacBook Pro retina 2012 vertical line

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

I have this vertical line at the side of my MacBook Pro, any idea what could be causing this/how to fix it?[image]

Comment: Chances are, it's your display.  Try running [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected.  If it's still there, then it's definitely hardware.  It's time to take it in for service.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an issue with your display, your flex cable, or some thing in the graphics part of your motherboard (a bad gpu, bad gpu solder balls, or a bad tantalum capacitor for the gpu).

If you feel comfortable, reseat the video flex cable and see if that solves it. If you don't feel comfortable opening your laptop, you'll need to take it in for repair.

Messing around inside a computer can always cause issues, even for experienced technicians, so if you feel uncomfortable doing it, don't risk it. You could permanently damage components.

Comment: I've always wanted to try some hardware soft but that's my fear. If you break something it's broken permanently or extremely expensive to repair. But software, anything that devastating will usually be fixed by a reinstall.

Comment: If you research, take your time, it's pretty easy. Sometimes mistakes can happen, but often it's minor, unless you drop a motherboard or scrape components off the board.